# I need to add the price for each level (pine script) support and resistance?

Tags: pine-script

would like to request help to add the price for each level support and resistance....

have tried several times, but it didn't work with me and  try to use this function `line.get_price` but it's not work...

I hope the question is clear

If possible, please help

---

https://kr.tradingview.com/script/6waJSyOJ-Classic-Levels/

---

### the code is (pine script)

```html
//@version=4
study("Classic_Levels", overlay=true)
distance = input(250, 'Time range', input.integer, minval=5, step=10)
sensitivity = input(1, 'Sensitivity', input.float, minval=0.1, step=0.1)
float wOpenClose = 1
float wHighLow = 0.5
float wCross = 0.5
int n_intervals = 300
int block_size = 11

// minimum and maximum values
float min_value = barstate.islast? low[-lowestbars(distance)]: 0
float max_value = barstate.islast? high[-highestbars(distance)]: 0

float sens = barstate.islast? 
 2 / (sensitivity * (wOpenClose + wHighLow + wCross)) : 0

if barstate.islast    
    m = array.new_int(n_intervals + 1, 0)
    r = array.new_float(n_intervals + 1, 0)
    a = array.new_float(block_size, 0)
    
    int i_close = na
    int i_open = na
    int i_high = na
    int i_low = na
    int mn = na
    int mx = na
    float interval_size = (max_value-min_value) / float(n_intervals)
    for k = 1 to distance-1
        i_close := floor((close[k]-min_value) / interval_size)
        i_open := floor((open[k]-min_value) / interval_size)
        i_high := floor((high[k]-min_value) / interval_size)
        i_low := floor((low[k]-min_value) / interval_size)
        array.set(r, i_close, array.get(r, i_close) + wOpenClose)
        array.set(r, i_open, array.get(r, i_open) + wOpenClose)
        array.set(r, i_high, array.get(r, i_high) + wHighLow)
        array.set(r, i_low, array.get(r, i_low) + wHighLow)
        array.set(m, i_close, array.get(m, i_close) + 1)
        array.set(m, i_open, array.get(m, i_open) + 1)
        array.set(m, i_high, array.get(m, i_high) + 1)
        array.set(m, i_low, array.get(m, i_low) + 1)
        if abs(i_open-i_close) >= 2
            mn := min(i_open, i_close)
            mx := max(i_open, i_close)
            for i = mn+1 to mx-1
                array.set(r, i, array.get(r, i) - wCross)
                array.set(m, i, array.get(m, i) + 1)

    float cur_block = 0
    float extr_block = 0
    int extr_val = 0
    float level_val = 0
    bool state = false
    float cur_sum = 0
    for i = 0 to n_intervals+block_size-2
        array.shift(a)
        if i < n_intervals
            array.push(a, array.get(r, i) / array.get(m, i))
        else
            array.push(a, 0)
        cur_block := array.sum(a)
        if not state
            if i == 0 or cur_block > extr_block
                extr_block := cur_block
                extr_val := i-block_size+1
            else
                if extr_block - cur_block >= sens or
                 i == n_intervals - 1
                    level_val := min_value + 
                     interval_size * (extr_val + float(block_size) / 2)
                    line.new(bar_index-1, level_val, bar_index, level_val, 
                     style=line.style_solid, extend=extend.both, 
                      color=color.blue, width=1)
                    extr_block := cur_block
                    extr_val := i-block_size+1
                    state := true
        else
            if cur_block < extr_block
                extr_block := cur_block
                extr_val := i-block_size+1
            else
                if cur_block - extr_block >= sens
                    extr_block := cur_block
                    extr_val := i-block_size+1
                    state := false
plotshape(barstate.islast, style=shape.circle, color=color.navy, 
 size=size.tiny, offset=-distance)
```

Thanks for your cooperation

Comment: the script appears to use lines to draw the levels, so your question is not clear

Comment: I need to highlight a price above each level

Comment: where the lines are being drawn ```line.new``` you can add ```label.new``` and show the value ```level_val```

Answer (score -1):

```
label.new(bar_index + div, level_val, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white, text=str.tostring(level_val,format.mintick) + ' ' + 'Salem' , yloc=yloc.price)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: The answer was based on – John Baron's an answer, Thanks